# Is client side templating suitable for products?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

Are client side templates suitable for developing products ? Would this not expose considerable amount of logic to customers ?

Comment: Is your concern that "proprietary" code would be sent to the browser, or one of performance, executing logic client-side instead of server side?

Answer (score 1):

It's true the client-side script is open and can be viewed by users. However, it's also true the .NET languages can be effectively decompiled as well.

However, this does not mean both cannot be used to "develop products".

"Products" can be open source unless there is something specific about them that make this prohibitive.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirements of your web application. Here are some considerations:

If you have a very traditional page load model, where the contents of the page are known and not subject to change after page load, then building the HTML on the server-side is ideal.

If you have AJAX updates to the content, you can still build the HTML server-side and send down strings of HTML to be inserted into the DOM.

Now, maybe you have a rich UI that calls for building new HTML content dynamically and templating seems like a good fit. Maybe you click add line item and you need a row built and added with input boxes, for example. Now it's probably faster to use templating. You can avoid the service calls to the server for HTML and build it client-side instead.

Even when service calls are still necessary, you might have reason to use templating. It really depends on what else is going on with the content and any model representations associated with your app.

I wouldn't be concerned about sending certain logic client-side these days. It is not likely your templating code is of any IP sensitive nature. Performance-wise, you may end up with a more responsive user experience if you're not waiting for a server response when JavaScript can handle everything more quickly.